# ASP.NET MVC 2 - simple increment value in database by submit in view

Tags: database, linq, asp.net-mvc-2, submit, html.beginform

I'm guessing  is very simple, but I'm learning MVC 2 right now and I'm stuck. I've got strongly typed view with some fields and buttons which should change something in database by click on them. So it is code

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("UpVote", "Home",FormMethod.Post,new { linkId = link.LinkID }))
   {%>
        <input type="submit" value="UP" />
<% } %>
```

And my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public void UpVote(int linkId)
{
    var updateLink = geekDB.Link.Single(a => a.LinkID == linkId);
    updateLink.UpVotes++;
    geekDB.SaveChanges();

    RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

And it doesn't work. When i press button, page is reloaded but nothing happens. I checked it with breakpoint in UpVote method but it never stop there and I have no idea why.

Comment: create another question, post your code from controller, view and generated html

Comment: Ok, that's probably good idea :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

all your Actions should be `ActionResult`, you did void o_O

you could also put ViewResult,ContentResult RedirectRe.. but they are all `ActionResult`

Comment: It helped. I didn't know that I always need to return something. I wanted just to increment one thing.

Comment: well, in your case you return RedirectToAction("Index")

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1):

I would first check your routes.

Also your current use of BeginForm isn't proper as it would produce `<form action="/Home/UpVote" linkid="yourlinkid" method="post">` when I suspect you want it to be something like `<form action="/Home/UpVote?linkid=yourlinkid"...>` - swapping the last two parameters will produce that output like so:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("UpVote", "Home",new { linkId = link.LinkID }, FormMethod.Post)) {%>
        <input type="submit" value="UP" />
<% } %>
```

The rest of your stuff looks just fine without knowing more about your project.

Comment: Yeah, it also could be a problem, but main issue was in not returning a thing. But thanks :)